# Use docker to migrate a system

Tags: docker, containers, linux-containers

I have an aws ec2 account, where I am running couple of web apps on nginx. I don't know much about docker, except it is a container that takes snapshot of filesystem. Now, for some reason I am forced to switch accounts. I have opened a new aws ec2 account. Can I use docker to set up a container in my old virtual system, then get an image and deploy in my new system? This way I can remove the headache of having to install many components, configure nginx and all applications in my new system. Can I do that? If so, how?

Answer (score 1):

According to the best practices of Docker and its [CaaS](https://blog.docker.com/2016/02/containers-as-a-service-caas/), images are not supposed to "virtualize" a whole lot of services, on the contrary. Docker does not aim at taking a snapshot of the system (it uses FS overlay to create images, but theses are not snapshots).

So basically, if your (yet unclear) question is: "Can I virtualize my whole system into one image" the answer is: "No".

What you can do is using an image for each of your service (you'll find everything you need on the [hub.docker](http://hub.docker.com/)) to keep a clean system on your new one.

Another solution would be to list all the installed Linux packages on your old system, and installed them on the new one and copy all the configuration files.